# "An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-7

I've written an IP multicasting application in C#. It compiles fine, but at runtime  this line:

```
sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,
                     SocketOptionName.AddMembership,
                     new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse("224.100.0.1")));
```

throws an unhandled socket exception:

> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

I searched for the error in Google and people have suggested to remove the 3GB switch (my OS is Windows 7) which may have been enabled. I did that, but still get the same error. What could be the issue?

Comment: In my case it was a malware on the machine that tried to connect to an unknown site too many times.

Answer (score 24):

It could be port exhaustion. 
When application(s) makes too many outgoing connections in short time frame or does not dispose outgoing connections properly - you run out of ports.

[Here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160118151510/http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend.aspx) is the link to rather lengthy explanation and a way to diagnose the issue

Answer (score 14):

This seems to happen when you run out of resources (sockets?) or memory.
At the command prompt run:
netstat -ab

I'm not sure off hand what the socket limit is.  I'm currently fighting an issue like this myself.

Notes on socket limits:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196271

Answer (score 7):

You can encounter this error message if resource limits are being exceeded. A `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` implements `IDisposable`. Are you disposing of your socket(s) once you're finished with them?

Leaving them around for the garbage collector is an excellent way to leak resources.

Comment: I'm having this same problem with HTTP posts. Doing a large number of them in quick succession seems to overload IIS even though I'm disposing them properly with `using`. Ideas?

Comment: @jocull Where's your application? On a client machine talking to IIS or being hosted by IIS?

Comment: http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html might help explain limits imposed by the operating system as well.

Comment: It's a .NET console application talking to IIS. Basically SQL requests are being proxied through a web application.

Comment: @jocull I am having the exact same issue. Our webapp does many http posts and it eventually starts failing, I have tried a static instance of httpclinet and using version both donot work.

Answer (score 3):

I have this same error, but only on Windows 7.  If I run my same multicast app on Vista it works.  It pops up a system dialog to unblock the behavior from the app, but it runs.  This is probably a changed networking permissions thing in win7.  I'm still looking for a solution.  If someone else finds one, please post.

Answer (score 2):

see - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553549  and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929851 (you determine how many dynamic outbout ports you want).  Along with this second article, set the TcpTimedWaitDelay to dword decimal value of 30.  So when sockets get released to the system, the clear faster.
See - technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938217.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue (a.k.a error 10055) when trying to connect to a local MySQL database. I believe you need to raise the number of dynamic ports that the operating system allows.

The solution that worked for me was mentioned [here](http://blog.whitesites.com/blog.aspx?key=635140180116307813)
I believe it may help you as well, since you are using Windows. 
Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error on Windows Server 2008. In my case, after restart the server (with 2 years uptime) problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Got this error when contacting an external email provider in Sweden called Loopia on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter x64.

The server had not been rebooted for almost a year. After rebooting everything worked.

[image]

> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system
>   lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
>   194.9.94.72:993
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack
>   trace for more information about the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An
>   operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked
>   sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full 194.9.94.72:993

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and noticed that there were a lot of old/forgotten custom background processes running on the server and consuming sockets. Even the same processes run remotely by different users.

A brief cleanup via Task Manager did the job. Or reboot could be an option if you can.