# Stress testing .NET program throws exceptions on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-10, ddos

I have this method from a stress testing program I wrote:

```
void UdpStress(IPEndPoint destination)
{
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 255 };
    Socket s = new Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
     while (true) 
         s.SendTo(data, destination); 
}
```

After running this method, I get the following exception in less than 1 second:

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full`

I ran it on Windows 8 and it worked just fine.

I upgraded to Windows 10 about 2 weeks ago and now it doesn't work. I suspect it has something to do with a modified Socket API in Windows 10, or something.

So, where is this error coming from? And why does this happen now in Windows 10, but didn't happen at all in Windows 8?

**EDIT:** The answers on the other question don't solve my problem. They suggest things like port exhaustion, which might be possible but never happened to me before I upgraded to Windows 10. The program worked perfectly fine on Windows 8 but now, for a reason I'm struggling to understand, doesn't work on Windows 10 because of this exception. Additionally, an answer there says it works on Vista but not on 7, which suggests there's something different between OSes that limits that stress testing program. What is this? Can I solve it somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415175/an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-suffi)

Comment: @Stijn I already have seen this question, but the thing is that it didn't happen to me at all before Windows 10. I have no idea what should cause a port exhaustion, I just know that it ran fine before I upgraded to Windows 10. Maybe Microsoft changed something that broke it?

Comment: Possibly. Have you tried running your code on another Windows 10 machine, to make sure that it just isn't this specific machine causing an issue?

Comment: @Stijn I actually haven't tried because I don't have another one available, but I tested it on another Windows 8 machine and it works fine there. Could it be a memory/socket API limitation that can be bypassed somehow? Maybe the OS is limiting memory to the process in some way that makes the exception get thrown?

Comment: It is a given that the OS will make *some* attempt at getting the UDP datagram across without just dropping it on the floor.  You don't give it a decent shot at it.  Reminding you that your code is borken and can never work in practice isn't exactly a bug.  You'll have to talk to Microsoft to make your case, don't expect them to be terribly receptive however.