# warning : mysqli_connect() : an operation on the socket cannot be performed because system lacked buffer space

Tags: php, mysql

We are developing an app in php using windows. I am having a weird problem, on a page when I use php to query mysql to load data from mysql with large number of rows, I receive the subject mentioned error.

The error persists for about 30-45 seconds if page is reloaded within that time frame, while goes off after that and page loads correctly.

I am stuck and didn't find any suitable answer. I would like to know the following:

1. whether the problem is with server running apache or that running mysql since in our case both are running on different physical machines
2. where should i look in to resolve the issue

thanx in advance

regards
abhay

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't really belong on SO, because this isn't really an SQL error (most likely). There are a couple solutions by MS, found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2009/03/09/understanding-the-error-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full/

You could also have a look at this post on SO: ["An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415175/an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-suffi) - it's about C#, but the solutions should be appliccable.