# WinError 10055 when trying to launch jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to relaunch the jupyter notebook but it shows me the error message below. I am working with anaconda (base(root) environment). It used to launch properly but the problem occurs when I remotely connect through VPN. Can anyone help?

```
   [WinError 10055] An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\application.py", line 270, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 844, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 2037, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1711, in init_webapp
    success = self._bind_http_server()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1718, in _bind_http_server
    return self._bind_http_server_unix() if self.sock else self._bind_http_server_tcp()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1744, in _bind_http_server_tcp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 152, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 165, in add_sockets
    self._handlers[sock.fileno()] = add_accept_handler(
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 240, in add_accept_handler
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 265, in current
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 636, in get_event_loop
    self.set_event_loop(self.new_event_loop())
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 656, in new_event_loop
    return self._loop_factory()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 61, in __init__
    self._make_self_pipe()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 108, in _make_self_pipe
    self._ssock, self._csock = socket.socketpair()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 596, in socketpair
    lsock.bind((host, 0))
OSError: [WinError 10055] An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full
Exception ignored in: <function BaseEventLoop.__del__ at 0x00000190479EA1F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 656, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 92, in close
    self._close_self_pipe()
  File "C:\Users\tassa\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\selector_events.py", line 99, in _close_self_pipe
    self._remove_reader(self._ssock.fileno())
AttributeError: '_WindowsSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute '_ssock'
```

Comment: Try checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18079954/13746389) answer. While the original question concerns C#, the issue is very similar, and I believe the above answer gives a sufficient explanation.

Comment: It works find when I rerun the jupyter in the office. I cannot do rerun remotely. My colleauge mentions it maybe the proxy conflict while working remotely.